# How to check day is last date of month in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to check if a day is the last day of the month and if it is, for a function to return true, otherwise return false.

For example, if I pass in an argument of "Sun, 30 Jun 2013", the function is to return true, because it is the last day of the month, however if I pass in the argument "Mon, 03 Jun 2013" the function is to return false.

How can this be accomplished using Ruby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
def is_last_day(mydate)
    mydate.month != mydate.next_day.month 
end
```

Comment: this takes date object and not string ... it can be converted like chris'

Comment: +1. I like the use of `next_day` better than `date + 1`. It's a bit clearer and more self-documenting.

Comment: next_day is Rails, not Ruby.

Comment: I am afraid you are not right http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_day

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Rails, you can always do this as well:

```
date == date.end_of_month
```

or to check the end of *this* month:

```
date == Date.today.end_of_month
```

Comment: Your code only checks if it's the end of *this* month, it should be `Date.parse(str) == Date.parse(str).end_of_month`

Comment: @TheCha͢mp, go ahead and edit that in if you like. Better if both remain, so readers can pick whichever suits their use case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the date with [`DateTime.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse). `DateTime.parse` has built-in support for many date formats (including those in your example), but you can always use [`DateTime.strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) for more complex formats.
2. See if the next day is 1 (first day of next month) by using [`Date#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2B).

   ```
   require 'date'

   def last_day?(date_string)
     date = DateTime.parse(date_string)
     (date + 1).day == 1
   end

   puts last_day?('Sun, 30 Jun 2013') # true
   puts last_day?('Mon, 03 Jun 2013') # false
   ```